# WordPress w/ CiviCRM - Using Gutenberg in CiviMail

Tags: civimail

Small bit of background, I volunteered with a charity and helped implement a Drupal 7 / Civi install a few years ago. So I know enough to get around Civi before looking at any more recent changes.

I am a member of a non-profit organisation where a members website is needed. The user-base is such that I am thinking a WordPress / Civi build is more appropriate to make better use of Gutenberg. My question is, can you use Gutenberg as an editor for CiviMail?

I am just thinking about ease of use, compared to the users who would need to use it.

Comment: I don't think there would be an easy way to do that and also the editor would probably not necessarily deliver nice looking emails. However if your aim is to have a nice editor for responsive emails you may want to take a look at the CiviCRM Mosaico extension: https://civicrm.org/extensions/email-template-builder

Comment: Hi Fabian. Thanks, Mosaico might work as the issue is more that I want to make it simple and fast for others to write their CiviMails when they don't really have much experience with more than writing plain text mail to start with.

Comment: Fabian - want to add that as the Answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML email is a bear, even with templated services like MailChimp. For that reason Civimail will not be compatible with Gutenberg. Why? Because most HTML5 editors are not compatible with email-style HTML. In order to ensure that an HTML email looks pretty much the same for all users across platforms, you end up having to use old-school borderless tables with styles embedded in the HTML. Style sheets and divs simply don't translate to email because html mail protocol is still over a decade behind browser html technology. Develop a simple html mail template with borderless tables and embedded styles. Make the template a fixed width of 500px. Even more critical is whether the email has images embedded or stored on your site, but that's beyond the scope of this response.

Frankly, younger users eschew email altogether at this point. You're better off creating a short text, twitter or instagram post with links to a news or newsletter post on your WP site. Of course your post on the WP site itself would be Gutenberg friendly.

Edit: Of course you could also go with an extension like CiviCRM Mosaico as Fabian suggested above. ;)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. That makes sense and to be fair I should have known better.

As for Mosaico; it looks like it would be something that I could work with to get the same effect that I have in my mind at the moment, so I am going to have a play with it and see what it will come up with.